# How to remove app by xcode from device or simulator?

Tags: android, xcode

In Android Studio its possible to uninstall app from simulator or real device by terminal or plugin(as I show in below image).How can I do the same in Xcode?Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove from device:

- In Xcode: open Window menu/Devices
- Select the device
- Select the app to remove and press "del"

Remove from Simulator:

It is not possible to remove an app from Simulator using Xcode. You can do it using the Simulator itself:

a) Long press

- In simulator, long-press on the app icon
- click the appearing "x" to remove the app

b) Reset

- In Simulator: open Simulator menu/Reset Content and Settings